# Expandable List in javafx like android

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

In Android There is a ListView Like This
[image]

How Can This be acheived in Java FX, Any links, suggestion or Custom Components ? I goggled and did not find any? however the closely related is Accordion but it does not suit look and feel. it should b like a LIST with evenly sized cells. any Help? I am using JavaFx 2.

## Edit:

As suggested in comments that tree view can help me. Ok. But i tried to use tree view and i also read this blog post http://myjavafx.blogspot.com/2012/03/treeview-with-data-source.html
but how can I customize the one row. i mean how can i map or bind the data from my Alerts POJO to different labels and image views .
e.g some thing like

```
TreeView<Alerts> tv = new TreeView<>(new Alerts("Incedent Name","Alerts Title",
                "Short Message","Sender",new Date(),new Image("titleImage.png"),
                typeColor));
```

and all these value mapped to corresponding Labels and Images to in a single row.
As There is no Expandable List right now offered by JavaFX so I think this approach. can any body have suggestions or sample mapping code etc.

Comment: By customizing and styling the [Tree View](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm)

Comment: I had seen this link and also tried to customize but  no luck, any working example I am new to Javafx

Comment: Observe the [List View](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm). In this link there is a customization of listview. The same concept is also applicable to treeview, you will need to work with treecell. If still having troubles, please provide the code that have done so far.

Comment: @UlukBiy this is not expandable list. it is simple list which is already i am using but now requirement has change and i have to add expand feature to one row . e.g i have two types of alerts, simple and grouped. grouped alerts has parent child relation so on expanding parent its child alerts will be revealed. I just need a way by which i have expandable feature then comes the customization part. I tried tree view but was not able to make look like in picture.

Comment: any help , any starting point from where i can customize tree?

Comment: Did you manage to code a working version that answered your question? Like a "port" of Android's ExpandableListView to javaFX? @Mubasher

Answer (score 2):

Here is a startup sample code:

```
public class TreeDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TreeItem<Alert> rootNode = new TreeItem<>(new Alert("dummy", "dummy"));
        rootNode.setExpanded(true);
        TreeItem<Alert> groupNode = new TreeItem<>(new Alert("group item", "group item"));
        groupNode.getChildren().addAll(new TreeItem<>(new Alert("sub item 1", "sub item 1")),
                new TreeItem<>(new Alert("sub item 2", "sub item 2")),
                new TreeItem<>(new Alert("sub item 3", "sub item 3")));

        rootNode.getChildren().addAll(new TreeItem<>(new Alert("item 1", "item 1")),
                groupNode,
                new TreeItem<>(new Alert("item 2", "item 2")),
                new TreeItem<>(new Alert("item 3", "item 3")));

        VBox box = new VBox();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(box, 400, 300);
        scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);

        TreeView<Alert> treeView = new TreeView<>(rootNode);
        treeView.setShowRoot(false);
        treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<Alert>, TreeCell<Alert>>() {
            @Override
            public TreeCell<Alert> call(TreeView<Alert> p) {
                return new AlertTreeCell();
            }
        });

        box.getChildren().add(treeView);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private final class AlertTreeCell extends TreeCell<Alert> {

        private final AnchorPane anchorPane;
        private final Label label;
        private final Button button;

        public AlertTreeCell() {
            anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
            label = new Label();
            button = new Button();
            anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(label, button);
            anchorPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: gray");
            anchorPane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(button, 10.0);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(label, 15.0);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Alert item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                setText(null);
                label.setText(item.getStatus());
                button.setText(item.getName());
                setGraphic(anchorPane);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Alert {

        private final SimpleStringProperty name;
        private final SimpleStringProperty status;

        private Alert(String name, String department) {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.status = new SimpleStringProperty(department);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public void setName(String fName) {
            name.set(fName);
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status.get();
        }

        public void setStatus(String fName) {
            status.set(fName);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

- There is only one root in treeview, so to display list like screen, we do

  ```
  rootNode.setExpanded(true);
  treeView.setShowRoot(false);
  ```
- I used Anchorpane as a layout for the cell, since it seems to fit better with your gui design.
- You should probably use css file, and move all inline styling into it

Comment: Thanks for your input, Let me try this.

Comment: You made tree cells by code, can it moved to FXML or can i set its layout by fxml

Comment: You can't move cell definition to fxml, but you can define its layout in fxml. In treecell constructor you need to load the fxml file and use it as a "graphic".

Comment: @Mubasher Were you able to implement?

Comment: yes your code is perfectly working. although look and feel i mean GUI is not like i want but I know i need to apply css , yes I want its cells layout in fxml, One thing I noted is that on click it highlighted the cell with default blue color, how to avoid this? and 2nd most important question can i sort this tree view on different cell values e.g sort by alert date, sort by receive. But man you clearly give me starting point and for this Thanks

Comment: The css styling and laying out are left to you. You can easily do them after reading the Oracle's layout tutorial and css reference guide. For removing highlight color you need to override treview's default css properties in caspian.css (JavaFX 2.2) or in modena.css (JavaFX 8) files. Search the stackoverflow with something like this ["listview row color"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+or+%5Bjavafx-2%5D+or+%5Bjavafx-8%5D+listview+row+color+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: Treeview hasn't built in sorting feature. You need to do it manually by reconstructing the items, or use the code from blog post you have linked in your question.

Comment: I am working on it. as soon i finished I will update your ans so to help others and accept it as answer. If I face any issue i will ask you say tuned. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mubasher if the further questions are not related to this answer please start new Q&A entry.

Comment: I saw a strange behavior in tree by your code as well using just Strings as Type argument. suppose we have just like above code tree view with String type. When Tree View is collapsed and we select just below the grouped cell , which is collapsed, and then we expand the collapsed cell. i saw two cells are now selected. one that i have selected when group cell was not expanded, and other just below or you can say on same position when selected. is not this weird? is this a bug in TreeView?